# I want to de-spaghettify this function

Tags: node.js

How can I make this function better? I don't like the fact I have to use a `forEach` to define manipulable content. I was thinking of running a reduce on find, but It's all too confusing for me.

```
_replace (content, find, replace, delimiter = '', findDelimiter = '') {
  if (!Array.isArray(find)) find = [find]
  let result = content
  find.forEach(ref => {
    result = result.split(findDelimiter).reduce((a, e) => a + delimiter + (this._reference[replace][this._reference[ref].indexOf(e)] || e), '')
  })
  return result
}
```

Comment: what are your inputs and what is your desired output?

Comment: If this is working code that you want advice on improving, then it belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com (not here) and you should carefully follow the posting rules when posting there as they require a specific format for title and body.  You also need to describe exactly what the function is supposed to do with example inputs and outputs.

Comment: Sorry, first time. `content` is a string you want to run the replace on, `find` is an array (or an array of arrays) of characters you want to find, `replace` is an array of characters you want to replace with (matching indices), the `delimiter` is what separates each character in `content`, and `findDelimiter` is what separates each replace.